# Unsubscribe observable in an Angular service

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I want to unsubscribe an observable in an angular service once a certain state is present. The unsubscribe should be executed within the subscription. Unfortunately the code below does not work.

```
@Injectable()
export class CartManagementUsecase {
  private unsubscribe = new Subject();

  public streamSession(): void {
    this.adapter
        .streamSession()
        .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe))
        .subscribe((session) => {
          if(session.session_state === SessionState.CLOSED) {
            this.unsubscribe.unsubscribe();
          }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: The question is why you are doing a subscription inside a service method in the first place?

Comment: `this.unsubscribe.next()` instead of `this.unsubscribe.unsubscribe()`

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend you to take events untill `closed` is come. no subject would be required

```
public streamSession(): void {
    this.adapter
        .streamSession()
        .pipe(takeWhile(session => session.session_state != SessionState.CLOSED))
        .subscribe((session) => {
          // do something that is required
        });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `complete` on your subject for `takeUntil` to unsubscribe to the observable.

```
@Injectable()
export class CartManagementUsecase {
  private unsubscribe = new Subject();

  public streamSession(): void {
    this.adapter
        .streamSession()
        .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe))
        .subscribe((session) => {
          if(session.session_state === SessionState.CLOSED) {
            this.unsubscribe.complete();
          }
    });
  }
}
```